# Piwik Page Name Not Defined

Tags: javascript, matomo

Thank you for this great program, it is far superior to Adobe Omniture, which I inherieted from another web programmer.

I have been following the documentation and all was working well as I was able to track page views a certain way. I was successful in tracking the page views in this manner. I have torn thru the code and the databases still confused. I have turned on the debugger as well.

The first example is a working example that works perfectly! (click on a video in the scroll)
Here is the site: http://widgets.digitalmediacommunications.com/all/embed/index/1/

http://xul.digitalmediacommunications.com/piwik/piwik.php?action_name=all%20%7C%202943143%20%7C%20Peach%20County%3A%20Equipment%20Operator%20%7C%20index&idsite=1&rec=1&r=237473&h=11&m=6&s=11&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwidgets.digitalmediacommunications.com%2Fall%2Fembed%2Findex%2F1%2F&_id=49f5164d43914f5c&_idts=1396111918&_idvc=18&_idn=0&_refts=1396626497&_viewts=1396623636&_ref=http%3A%2F%2Fxul.digitalmediacommunications.com%2Findex.php%2Fadmin%2Fpublications%2Fedit%2Fpublication%2F903&pdf=1&qt=1&realp=0&wma=1&dir=0&fla=1&java=0&gears=0&ag=0&cookie=1&res=2100x1313&gt_ms=704

However when I created a new website to track (siteid 6) This is where I get the "Page Name not defined":

http://widgets.digitalmediacommunications.com/widget/embed/index/?p=903&k=ban

Correction: this the debugging link to failed code:
[http://xul.digitalmediacommunications.com/piwik/piwik.php?action_name=0005132008-01%20|%20Quora%2C%20Inc.%3A%20Infrastructure%20Performance%20Engineer&idsite=6&rec=1&r=123305&h=11&m=3&s=7&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwidgets.digitalmediacommunications.com%2Fwidget%2Fembed%2Findex%2F%3Fp%3D903%26k%3Dban&_id=1e9c3c7c7fed0551&_idts=1396630987&_idvc=1&_idn=0&_refts=0&_viewts=1396630987&pdf=1&qt=1&realp=0&wma=1&dir=0&fla=1&java=0&gears=0&ag=0&cookie=1&res=2100x1313&gt_ms=455](http://xul.digitalmediacommunications.com/piwik/piwik.php?action_name=0005132008-01%20%7C%20Quora%2C%20Inc.%3A%20Infrastructure%20Performance%20Engineer&idsite=6&rec=1&r=123305&h=11&m=3&s=7&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwidgets.digitalmediacommunications.com%2Fwidget%2Fembed%2Findex%2F%3Fp%3D903%26k%3Dban&_id=1e9c3c7c7fed0551&_idts=1396630987&_idvc=1&_idn=0&_refts=0&_viewts=1396630987&pdf=1&qt=1&realp=0&wma=1&dir=0&fla=1&java=0&gears=0&ag=0&cookie=1&res=2100x1313&gt_ms=455)

For some reason I can't seem to get this particular action inserted into piwik_log_action?

Answer (score 0):

I have been sucessful in tracking page titles on the few sites:
such as: bestoftheinternets.com or widgets.digitalmediacommunications.com/all/embed/index/2. (These urls are inputed in as in website managment)

This is the response that I get from a successful page view:
this is not a Site Search request)
Action is a PAGE_URL, Action name = Black Weekend Update March 15, 2014, Action URL = http://www.bestoftheinternets.com/

However the website that has been giving "page name not defined" is the following: http://widgets.digitalmediacommunications.com/widget/embed/index/?p=903&k=ban (This is the also entered in as the URL in website management)

Notice the K=ban.

When I debug that website:

Detected Site Search keyword 'ban'.
NOTE: The Page URL was changed / removed, during the Site Search detection, was 'http://widgets.digitalmediacommunications.com/widget/embed/index/?p=903&k=ban', now is 'http://widgets.digitalmediacommunications.com/widget/embed/index/?p=903'
Action is a SITE_SEARCH, Action name = ban, Action URL = http://widgets.digitalmediacommunications.com/widget/embed/index/?p=903

I'm think that somehow my k=ban is triggering piwik site search feature. So when I turned off site search it worked! I will reviste this issue if I choose to work with site search someday.

In the meantime, thanks for maintain Piwik, because I don't know if you have ever had the misery of working with Omniture (Adobe), but I assure there is no greater HELL!